# Sql query for data excluding current date

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I want to select last 3 days data excluding Current date.

I am trying something like below on Snowflake.

```
select * from Table where S_date <= DATEADD(DAY, -3, current_date-1) .
```

But it is also including current date too.

Please help.

Comment: Edit your question and tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I am trying it on snowflake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Standard SQL, the syntax would be:

```
where S_date >= current_date - interval '3 day' and
      S_date < current_date
```

This works in some databases.  But databases typically have their own date/time functions, so the syntax likely needs to be customized to your database.

In Snowflake:

```
where S_date >= dateadd(day, -3, current_date) and
      S_date < current_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not say what platform you are running on.  On sql server this will work

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE S_date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -3, current_date) AND DATEADD(DAY,-1, current_date)
```